# How to use socks in HtmlUnit

Tags: java, exception, htmlunit, socks

I've googled for three hours and found nothing helpful.
I have WebClient which connects to some sites through socks 5 which are not require to use login and password to work through them:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        wc.setProxyConfig(new ProxyConfig(socks.split(":")[0], Integer.parseInt(socks.split(":")[1]), true));
        wc.setTimeout(30000);
        wc.setCssEnabled(false);
        wc.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);
```

And so on. I recieve the next exception for EVERYONE alive host which don't require login or password:

```
java.net.SocketException: SOCKS : authentication failed
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:473)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.SocksSocketFactory.connectSocket(SocksSocketFactory.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:148)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:149)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:121)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:573)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:425)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:820)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:776)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.HttpWebConnection.getResponse(HttpWebConnection.java:152)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponseFromWebConnection(WebClient.java:1439)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.loadWebResponse(WebClient.java:1358)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:307)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:373)
    at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.getPage(WebClient.java:358)
    at mus.Gucol.run(Gucol.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

And

```
Dec 12, 2011 4:14:02 AM org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector tryConnect
INFO: I/O exception (java.net.SocketException) caught when connecting to the target host: SOCKS : authentication failed
```

HtmlUnit 2.9. I've tried to use credentials:

```
WebClient wc = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_3_6);
        wc.setProxyConfig(new ProxyConfig(socks.split(":")[0], Integer.parseInt(socks.split(":")[1]), true));
        wc.setTimeout(30000);
        wc.setCssEnabled(false);
        wc.setJavaScriptEnabled(false);

        final DefaultCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = (DefaultCredentialsProvider) wc.getCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.addCredentials("", "", socks.split(":")[0], Integer.parseInt(socks.split(":")[1]), null);
        credentialsProvider.addProxyCredentials("", "");

        wc.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
```

But it make no sense. And I think that problem is not in HtmlUnit but in Java because I've tried to use socks via HtmlUrlConnection and there is the same error happens and it makes me cry. Guys, how to make it working? I've spent about six hours on solving this issue and I can't use System.setProperty because I need different socks for each WebClient "window".

Comment: did you got the solution yet? I intend to use socks5 proxy with htmlunit, please share your solution in case you found one.

Comment: @XCoder sorry I have no sources now but yes there was some solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with a null value instead of an empty string?

BTW, addProxyCredentials() is deprecated

Comment: After setup null values to login&pass application don't work. Also I know about addProxyCredentials() but I have tried every solution and nothing happens.